# Error: Input string was not in a correct format

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

This is homework.  When I run this and click on the "Add Bike" button at the bottom of the page, the error occurs on this line:  **BikeBinding b = new BikeBinding {** of this method:

```
protected void btnAddBike_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            BikeBinding b = new BikeBinding {
                manufacturer = Manufacturer.Text,
                gears = int.Parse((Gears).Text),
                frame = Frame.Text
            };
```

Instead of int.Parse, I tried Int32.Parse for Gears, but still had the same error.  Thanks in advance.

```
using MvcApplication3.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace MvcApplication3

{
    public partial class WebFormBinding : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
    List<BikeBinding> bicycles;

    public void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bicycles = GetApplicationBicycles();

        FormView1.DefaultMode = FormViewMode.Edit;

        BindControls();

        // Page.DataBind

        // FormView1.DefaultMode = FormViewMode.Edit;
    }

    private void BindControls()
    {
        // Bind all DataBound Controls
        foreach (Control wc in PanelDataBoundControls.Controls)
        {
            if (wc is DataBoundControl)
            {
                DataBoundControl lc = (DataBoundControl)wc;
                // Response.Write("<br />" + lc.ToString());
                lc.DataSource = bicycles;
                lc.DataBind();
            }
        }

        // Not DataBound Controls, so I'll bind them by hand
        DataList1.DataSource = bicycles;
        DataList1.DataBind();

        Repeater1.DataSource = bicycles;
        Repeater1.DataBind();
    }

    private List<BikeBinding> GetApplicationBicycles()
    {
        return (List<BikeBinding>)Application["bicycles"];
    }

    protected void btnAddBike_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        BikeBinding b = new BikeBinding {
            manufacturer = Manufacturer.Text,
            gears = int.Parse((Gears).Text),
            frame = Frame.Text
        };
        bicycles.Add(b);

        // Saves the bicycle list to the Application object
        Application.Lock();
        Application["bicycles"] = bicycles;
        Application.UnLock();

        Manufacturer.Text = String.Empty;
        Gears.Text = String.Empty;
        Frame.Text = String.Empty;

        BindControls();

    }
}
}
```

namespace MvcApplication3
{

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    List<BikeBinding> bicycles;

    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

        WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);

        bicycles = new List<BikeBinding>();

        BikeBinding b = new BikeBinding { bikeID = 0, manufacturer = "Schwinn", gears = 10, frame = "Racing" };
        bicycles.Add(b);
        b = new BikeBinding { bikeID = 1, manufacturer = "Nishiki", gears = 5, frame = "Mountain" };
        bicycles.Add(b);

        b = new BikeBinding();
        b.bikeID = 2;
        b.manufacturer = "Trek Medone";
        b.gears = 7;
        b.frame = "Road";

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            BikeBinding x = new BikeBinding { bikeID = i, manufacturer = i.ToString(), gears = i, frame = i.ToString() };
            bicycles.Add(x);
        }

        // Saves the bicycle list to the Application object
        Application.Lock();
        Application["bicycles"] = bicycles;
        Application.UnLock();
    }

}
```

}

Comment: What is the value of `Gears.Text`?

Comment: an int.  I added code from Global.asax to my question just now.

Comment: I highly doubt it's an int. Try stepping through with the debugger and seeing what the actual value is.

Comment: Why is your namespace MvcApplication3 if you are using webforms.  Are you sure you setup your project correctly to begin with?

Comment: It goes to BikeBinding.cs, and here the value is 0: public BikeBinding()
            : this("Schwinn")
        {
        }

Answer (score 3):

If the textbox `Gears` contains a value that cannot be converted to an integer the `Parse` method throws an exception. So you need to change your code to handle this situation

```
protected void btnAddBike_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int g;
    if(!Int32.TryParse(Gears.Text, out g))
    {
        // some label where you could write the error message
        // labelError.Text = "An integer number is required.....";
        return;
    }
    BikeBinding b = new BikeBinding {
        manufacturer = Manufacturer.Text,
        gears = g,
        frame = Frame.Text
    };
    bicycles.Add(b);
    .....
```

The [TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method, instead of throwing an exception return false if the text cannot be converted to a integer number. If it is possible to convert then the value is assigned to the out variable passed as second parameter to TryParse

Comment: Yes, that happen because the Gears textbox is empty or contains a string  that cannot be converted to an integer by Int.Parse. So I suggest to use TryParse and check the return value of that method

Comment: MessageBox does not exist in the current context.  I placed using System.Windows.Forms; at the top, but there's an error with the Forms in that statement.

Comment: Right, I have failed to notice the asp.net tag. You should have some controls where you write your error text or you could simply return.

Comment: You could also try adding a validator like the ones explained here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479013.aspx

Comment: In Behavior, I could set CausesValidation to true?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42291/discussion-between-grafica-and-steve)